# Стили текста и кавычки

Tags: css

Почему некоторые стили текста с кавычками, а некоторые без?
Я встречал такие стили, но они все работают одинаково.

**Обязательно ли ставить кавычки, если нет, тогда зачем придумали кавычки?**

С кавычками

```css
font-family:'Arial';
```

Без кавычек

```css
font-family: Times New Roman;
```

Comment: Да без разницы - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/font-family#%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: тогда зачем придумали кавычки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам в комментариях дали ссылку на MDN: [Валидные имена семейства шрифтов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/font-family#%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).
Если семейство содержит цифры или спецсимволы, CSS его не распарсит.
И, как по мне, с кавычками просто выглядит лучше. Проще при беглом чтении понять, какой же шрифт установлен.
А так, если Вам нужно код обфусцировать, конечно убирайте кавычки - и файл стилей весит меньше, и читать сложнее!